# RegEx passes but fails on browsers

Tags: regex, email-validation

This RegEx for an email passes on http://scriptular.com, but fails all the browsers. Any ideas why? i tried a number of ways; but at this point, I am clueless.

```
   <!doctype html>
   <html lang="en">
   <head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <title>RegEx Test</title>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      function saveSignUp(){

      var warning = "The following field(s) require an entry: \n \n";
      var same = warning;
      var email = document.forms[0].email.value;
      // FIRST TEST
      /*var regExEmail= /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.-])+@([a-zA-Z0-9_.-])+\.([a-zA-Z])+/;*/
      // SECOND TEST
      var regExEmail= /[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]+/;
      if(email == ""){ warning += " - Email is required \n"; }
      else if(email != regExEmail){ warning += " - E-mail not formatted properly \n"; }

      if (warning == same){
        return true; 
      } 
      else { 
        alert(warning);     
      }
    return false;
    }
   </script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <form method="post" onsubmit="return saveSignUp()" action="signupSucces.html" >
        <input type="text" placeholder="Email" name="email">
        <input type="submit" class="button wide" value="Request an Account">        
      </form>
    </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: What are the not validated email addresses ?

Comment: Have you tried using the regex match instead of != comparison? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Working_with_Regular_Expressions

Comment: @zulu: Any alpha numeric with any underscores, periods or dashes in between followed by an @ then any alpha numeric, followed by a dot (.) and another alpha.
@ tommoyang: I haven't. I'll take a look.

Answer (score 2):

```
if(email != regExEmail)
```

This is not how you test a regex match. Use this instead:

```
if (!regExEmail.test(email))
```

And, you should encose your regex within `^`..`$` to check the whole string matches, not just a substring of it.

```
var regExEmail= /^[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]+$/;
```

Comment: @ryanjohnsond Meh, I inverted the logic. Here's the [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vz8oyuvo/4/). Also, for the fiddle to work, I had to change the script location (No wrap - in <head>)

Comment: That works! Thnx!  Not sure what you meant by "No wrap - in <head>"

Comment: @ryanjohnsond It's the script execution order (in this case the script will be processed before the form, just like if you put it in `<head>`).